# Can't stop loop in thread

Tags: java, multithreading

Can someone explain to me why my thread "m" isn't stopping when the logout jbutton is pushed? program seems to being hanging or in some infinite loop.I'm having trouble understanding what is going on with the thread in this case.

```
public class Log_GUI extends Jframe{
    private GUI talking;
    private volatile boolean[]go = new boolean[1]; 


                    go[0] = true;
                    setVisible(false);
                    GUI talking = new GUI(read_me,display_me,usr_name);
                    talking.create(go);


                    Thread m = new Thread(){
                      public void run(){

                          String me;
                          while (go[0]){

                              try
                              {


                                  try {
                                      me = (String) read_me.readObject();
                                      System.out.println(me);
                                      talking.sendme(me);

                                  }catch (ClassNotFoundException ClassNotfoundException){
                                  }
                              }catch (IOException IOException){
                              }
                          }
                      }

                    }; m.start();
                }

            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ClassNotFoundException) {

            }

    }catch (IOException IOException){

        }

        System.out.println("hello");
}
}



    public class GUI extends Jframe{

     public void create(boolean[]go){
       .........
         sign_out.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            go[0]=false;

        }
    });
    }
    }
```

Comment: `go` in `Log_GUI` is an array, `go` in `GUI` is a primitive, that's already suspicious. You also be marking them as `volatile`

Comment: i tried that and it didnt work :/

Comment: You seem to be in the illusion that the variables from one class are magically linked to the variables in another - which would answer the question of "why" it doesn't work. Personally, I'd have a look at `AtomicBoolean`, the same instance of this would need to be passed to both the `Thread` AND the `GUI` class

Comment: I passed var go to the GUI but i cant pass it into the threads run function, i tried the atomicboolean and volatile but didnt work either, i must be missing something.

Comment: Is `me = (String) read_me.readObject();` or `talking.sendme(me);` blocking?  If they are, then your loop exit condition won't be evaluated

Comment: Yes you are correct they are blocking because they wait for data to be read in and send.

Comment: If they support thread interruption, then I'd consider using a `FutureTask`, otherwise you might need to send it a "stop" message directly

Comment: I figured out the problem I will post a new question

Answer (score 0):

You have a concurrency issue.
`volatile boolean[]go = new boolean[1];` only solves visibility and atomicity for variable `go` but it does not provide any guarantees for the values inside the array.

In a nutshell if `thread 2` modifies `go[0]` to be `true`, `thread 1` might never see it...
if `thread 2` creates a new array and assigns it to `go` then `thread 1` will see it...

In method `actionPerformed()` you must do something like

```
boolean[] copy = copy(go);
copy[0] = false;
go = copy; // correct way to do it is CAS unless you know you are the only writer...
```

Also i dont understand the purpose of keeping array, in your case you could just keep one boolean flag (unless you intend to store multiple flags)...

If so you could do cheap concurrency using bitset approach, when you use single volatile int or long and set single bit in it... that allows you to have atomicity of change and visibility using single volatile for 32 or 64 flags...

Comment: I used an array to pass a reference so i wouldn't have to pass by value. And i tried your solution it didn't work

Answer (score -1):

Try removing the local variable `go[]` all together, always pick latest state from `talking.stop();`

Comment: What is this `stop()` method you're talking about?  In any case, I think this answer is too vague to be useful.  Some details would make this a better answer (if they're correct).

Comment: talking is not a thread, my thread is created inside a class that has a GUI called talking

Comment: @ajb what do you suggest

Comment: @ajb well, code snippet is updated and line is removed.